# Grid Mass Action with childs no longer work with 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3, grid, uicomponent

i updated from Magento 2.3.2 to 2.3.3, and one module has a problem with grid massactions.

The old way was:

```
            <action name="change_status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">change_status</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Change Status</item>
                    <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">company_module/customerchange/changeStatus</item>
                    <item name="paramName" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="actions" xsi:type="configurableObject">
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Ui\Component\MassAction\ChangeStatus</argument>
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">company_module/customerchange/changeStatus</item>
                    <item name="paramName" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Confirm</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure to change the status?</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </argument>
        </action>
```

After update i get the error message:
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Class argument is invalid: Company\Module\Ui\Component\MassAction\ChangeStatus

The code above was the only i found. Is there another right way to do this? Or is there an error in my code?

Regards,
Andreas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should change your code using example from any magento 2.3 listing, for example you can use the customer group change action in the customer grid:

See source model here:
[vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/MassAction/Group/Options.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Customer/Ui/Component/MassAction/Group/Options.php)

In `vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/di.xml` added some params:

```xml
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\MassAction\Group\Options">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">customer/index/massAssignGroup</item>
                <item name="paramName" xsi:type="string">group</item>
                <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translatable="true">Assign a Customer Group</item>
                    <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translatable="true">Are you sure to assign selected customers to new group?</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Finally, in
`vendor/magento/module-customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml`

```xml
            <action name="assign_to_group">
                <settings>
                    <type>assign_to_group</type>
                    <label translate="true">Assign a Customer Group</label>
                    <actions class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\MassAction\Group\Options"/>
                </settings>
            </action>
```

P.S. This example code is compatible with magento 2.2.x

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I found that in the customer module, but i did not know that there was a entry in di.xml, too.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: It's working perfect. Thank you...!!